# How to limit the number of available values in a slicer based on fact table?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

I have `Overall_Results` table that has `ProducerGUID` column. It contains approximately 146 unique `ProducerGUID`.

Table `Producer` (contains 1,300 unique `ProducerGUID`) joined with `Overall_Results` via `ProducerGUID`.

[image]

When using a slicer '`ProducerName`' it displays  all 1,300 different producers.

Is any way to limit the number of unique producers in a slicer and only display those that table `'Overall_results'` has? Which is approx 146 of them instead of 1,300?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would try is to make the relationship between `Overall_Results` and `ProducerGUID` cross-filter in both directions.

If that doesn't work, you could also try doing an inner join in the Query Editor so that only the matching ID values show up.

Comment: Thanks. So I always afraid that messing around with the relationship (both direction etc) will distort my real numbers? Can it be? Or I shouldn't worry about that?

Comment: If you aren't using the rest of those IDs in your report, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Cross filtered between `Overall_Results` and `ProducerGUID` didn't work.
 So to do INNER JOIN I should `Merge Queries as New` from `Overall_results` to `Producers`?

Comment: Take the `Producer` query an merge in `Overall_Results` matching on `ProducerGUID` and set it to an inner join. You'll get a new column, but you can just delete it.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks